# Heavy tail distribution - Weibull

Tags: statistics, probability, cdf, weibull

I know that the Weibull distribution exhibits subexponential heavy-tailed behavior when the shape parameter is < 1. I need to demonstrate this using the limit definition of a heavy tailed distribution:

[image]

for all [image]

How do I incorporate the cumulative distribution function (CDF) or any other equation characteristic of the Weibull distribution to prove that this limit holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CDF of the Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) is `1 - exp(-(x/lambda)^k) = P(X <= x)`.

So

```
P(X > x) = 1 - CDF = exp(-(x/lambda)^k),
```

and

```
lim exp(lambda * x) * P(X > x) = lim exp(lambda x) * exp( - (x/lambda)^k)
                               = lim exp(lambda x - x^k/lambda^k)
```

Since `k<1`, and x is large, and `lambda>0`,  `lambda x` grows large faster than `x^k/lambda^k` (the monomial with the greater exponent wins). In other words, the `lambda x` term dominates the `x^k/lambda^k` term. So `lambda x - x^k/lambda^k` is large and positive.

Thus, the limit goes to infinity.